# Change order of output based on if condition

Tags: php

I've build my nice page in PHP, but I would like to get a different output order based on the result of a if condition applied at the beginning of the page.
IE:

```
if(condition is true){
    block n1
    block n2 }

else{
    block n2
    block n1 }
```

Can you kindly advise on what's the best practices in this case?
I think a flag should solve the problem, but I'm struggling to understand how.

Comment: Sorry if I've not been clear, but I'm trying to find a solution without repeating the code for each possible order I need (twice in the example I posted)

Comment: At the moment, the best solution I could find myself is to put the blocks of code into separate files and use a if-else to recall the files in a different order using the "include" command. It works, but hopefully there's a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

You could prepare you blocks and then exactly what you wrote :

```
$block1 = "12345";
$block2 = "67890";

$inverted = true;

if ($inverted===true) {
    echo $block2.$block1;
} else {
    echo $block1.$block2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use array just like that

```
  $orders = ['a', 'b'];
  if (1 === 1) {
     $orders = ['b', 'a'];
  }
```

with this you don't need "else" part

```
  foreach ($orders as $order){
        echo $order."<br/>";
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't make any sense :)

Comment: Actually you can print or loop this array.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to this. One would be with `if` and `else` and if you have many possibilities, then `switch case` would be advisable.

```php
$check = 1;

if( $check === 1) { 
    echo `show 1`;
} else {
    echo 'It is not 1';
}

// OR 
switch($check) {
    case 1: 
        echo 'Show 1';
         break;
    case 2: 
        echo 'Show 2';
         break;
    case 3: 
        echo 'Show 3';
         break;
    default: 
      echo 'It is not 1,2,3';
}
```